# Why this behavior using Object.with method vs Object(name:name) for attribute assignment

Tags: oop, groovy, attributes, null

I am getting two different types of behavior while using what I believe to be to analogous forms of attribute assignment when instantiating a new object.

The language is Groovy

When I run this method which uses with, id is never set and remains null. All of the other attributes are set properly.

```
def newSubFnObj( row, id ) {
    def sf = new SubFunction()
    sf.with {
        function    = row.PGM_PROC_FUNC
        subfunction = row.PGM_PROC_SUBF
        name        = getFunctionName( row )
        level       = row.PGM_PROC_LEVEL
        id          = id
    }
    return sf
}
```

However, when I use this method id is set properly and I have no problems.

```
def newSubFnObj( row, id ) {
    def sf = new SubFunction(function   :row.PGM_PROC_FUNC,
                             subfunction:row.PGM_PROC_SUBF,
                             name       :getFunctionName( row ),
                             level      :row.PGM_PROC_LEVEL,
                             id         :id)
    return sf
}
```

For the sake of thoroughness, this method has the correct behavior as well.

```
def newSubFnObj( row, id ) {
    def sf = new SubFunction()
    sf.function    = row.PGM_PROC_FUNC
    sf.subfunction = row.PGM_PROC_SUBF
    sf.name        = getFunctionName(row)
    sf.level       = row.PGM_PROC_LEVEL
    sf.id          = id
    return sf
}
```

This is a third also related method for context purposes.

```
def setParentChildInformation( subfunctions ) {
    subfunctions.eachWithIndex { s, i ->
        if ( i > 0 ) {
            def parentNotFound = true
            def x = i
            while ( parentNotFound && x >= 0 ) {
                x--
                def possibleParent = subfunctions[x]
                if ( s.levelNumber > possibleParent.levelNumber ) {
                    parentNotFound = false
                    possibleParent.childSubfunctions << s.id
                    s.parentId = possibleParent.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more method for context purposes.

```
def getFunctionName( row ) {
    return "${row.PGM_PROC_FUNC}${row.PGM_PROC_SUBF}".toString()
}
```

Here is the code for the SubFunction class

```
class SubFunction {
    def id
    def parentId
    def name 
    def function
    def subfunction
    def level
    def levelNumber
    def rows = []
    def lines = []
    def statements = []
    def childSubfunctions = []
}
```

I am not so much concerned with which way of doing things is better. Using with is a groovier way of performing attribute assignment within an object. I just seek to shed some light on why exactly this behavior is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the argument to something else other than `id`.

Reason seems obvious. Closure arg of `with(Closure)` has delegate set to `SubFunction`, so it treats `id` as that of the object (which is null) instead of taking the `id` passed as argument to `newSubFnObj()` method.

```
def newSubFnObj( row, _id ) {
    def sf = new SubFunction()
    sf.with {
        function    = row.PGM_PROC_FUNC
        subfunction = row.PGM_PROC_SUBF
        name        = getFunctionName( row )
        level       = row.PGM_PROC_LEVEL
        id          = _id
    }
    return sf
}
```

Above should do.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That was a silly oversight. Can't have them named the same thing lol. Noob mistake.